# Does secure boot protect you from infected BIOS/firmware?

Tags: operating-systems, bios, secure-boot

About secure boot, I've visited intel's website and they said:

> The feature defines an entirely new interface between operating system and firmware/BIOS. When enabled and fully configured, Secure Boot helps a computer resist attacks and infection from malware.

So, if my firmware and/or BIOS is infected, does this mean that if I type a password (for example encryption password for linux) when secure boot is enabled it won't be recorded by infected BIOS and/or firmware ?

Comment: Under secure boot, your laptop will refuse to boot if UEFI is tampered with. It will throw you into UEFI recovery to flash last known good image.

Comment: But @CBHacking states here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102554/how-do-rootkits-other-low-level-malware-still-manage-to-load-on-systems-protec that secure boot code can be tampered and so other scenarios for secure boot failure. Could you explain me more how system knows if UEFI image is tampered

Comment: your secure boot code should not be tamperable with. Everything else is a design fault of the hardware. Of course, if that code has bugs, that breaks security and bugs might be allowing an attacker to do things like somehow making the system boot a modified UEFI. But this is a pretty steep requiremnt.

Comment: @Marcus thanks for the information.

Comment: @Light it's basically: "If implemented correctly, secure boot protects you from booting firmware that's not signed, but we can't prove it's implemented correctly"

Comment: @Marcus i think that answers my question, thanks.